# Setting up dependency lib for android project

Tags: android, ant, build, dependencies

I'm very new to android and also to android.

I wish to do build my project if I do `ant release`.

I'm getting an error like due to the fact that my dependency lib aren't added to path.

But when I add :

```
android.library.reference.1=lib/android-support-v4.jar
```

like this `local.properties` I get an error like this:

```
 lib/android-support-v4.jar resolve to a path with no project.properties file for project /home/ubuntu/test
```

Where I'm making the mistake. Thanks in advance.